# Url rewriting PHP APACHE

Tags: php, apache

I'm curently building a website and I want to be able to rewrite urls like this

if I have `foo.com/registration.php` i want `foo.com/registration`.

Same if i have a member zone with `foo.com/member.php` i want something like `foo.com/member/"membername"/` (the member name is stored in a session, or I can do a cookie).

I've already seen apache rewrite module, but i don't really understand it, or at least not enough to apply it to my website

Comment: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ Begin your quest for rewriting URLS here.

Comment: Note that `/registration` is the SEO-format URI produced by page links on your site, or typed in by a visitor. You will be using .htaccess to _rewrite_ it to `/registration.php` (see other answers for details), which is the form that your server and scripts can actually make use of.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Htaccess to convert your "http-friendly url" to your application.

For example:
When your url will be: http://www.domain.com/this/link.html

Your htaccess will be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?filepath=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

In your index.php you can get this filepath request by this:

```
$a_request_filepath = (empty($_GET['filepath'])) ? 'index' : $_GET['filepath'];
```

Your variable will have the value: this/link

For short explaination:
You will look for the requested path.
You remove .html from the filepath and send the rest of the path to index.php with a parameter of the path.
So index.php?filepath=this/link is the same page

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache 2.2.16 or later, [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) provides similar functionality than the Rewrite module in one line. It may be a little more performant since it doesn't invoke checks to see if the requested resource is a file or directory.

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
If somebody is interrested, I learned the concept with a simple tutorial (no advertising, I just think he's good teacher ^^) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD&index=1